# Scala - Inner map returns value ( not an option of that value )

Tags: scala

I have a map of maps (immutable)

```
private val map = mutable.Map[String, mutable.Map[String, MyObject]]()
```

and I wonder why

```
map.get(id).get(name)
```

returns `MyObject` while

```
map.get(id)
```

returns `Option[String, MyObject]]`

I want to get `Option[MyObject]` out of map of maps

Comment: Maps would return an Option not other objects. You will have to parse MyObject to Option in that case

Comment: but writing map.get(id).get(name) returns an object

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, you use `get(id)` which returns an Option.

In the second case, you call `get` first on the option which returns the inner Map and then only you use `Map("name")` which doesn't return an option but the actual value (this is the apply method of Map).

You're actually not calling `get(name)` but `get` and then `(name)`.

```
scala> Map("id" -> Map("name" -> 5)).get("id")
res8: Option[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]] = Some(Map(name -> 5))

scala> Map("id" -> Map("name" -> 5)).get("id").get
res9: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(name -> 5)

scala> Map("id" -> Map("name" -> 5)).get("id").get("name")
res10: Int = 5
```

mutable/immutable, same reasoning.

---

Thus to keep your initial way of doing (for the demonstration):

```
scala> Map("id" -> Map("name" -> 5)).get("id").get.get("name")
res11: Option[Int] = Some(5)
```

---

But this doesn't handle the case of `id` not being part of the first level Map.

The alternative would be:

```
Map("id" -> Map("name" -> 5)).get("id").flatMap(_.get("name"))
```

which performs the get on the value of the inner Map only if the value for `id` is not `None`.

In case you would have more levels of nesting of Maps this could become another viable alternative:

```
for {
  v1 <- Map("id" -> Map("name" -> 5)).get("id");
  v2 <- v1.get("name")
} yield v2
```

Comment: `get("id").get` is pointless. It could be replaced by `("id")`, but Jordan's answer is a better alternative.

Comment: This is for the demonstration. `.get("id").get.get("name")` is obviously not the right way to access this value.

Comment: Yes, but your answer doesn't actually say so or what is the right way.

Answer (score 3):

`.get(id)` is the safe version of trying to get the value from a key in a map rather than `map(id)` which is the same as `.map.apply(id)` which does not return an Option.

**To get what you want,**  `Option[MyObject]`, you will have to call `.get(id)` then call `flatMap` on the resulting `Option[mutable.Map[String, MyObject]]`

```
private val map = mutable.Map[String, mutable.Map[String, MyObject]]()
val id = "id"
val name = "name"
val thng: Option[MyObject] = map.get(id).flatMap { innerMap =>
  innerMap.get(name)
}
```

Shorthand:
`map.get(id).flatMap(_.get(name)) // returns Option[MyObject]`